# Read .mat dates with R

Tags: r, matlab, date

I'm using R and the `R.matlab` package to read Matlab .mat files. I have an issue regarding date representation.

Here is a very simple example. I saved a single datetime object in Matlab:

```
foo = datetime;
save('foo.mat', 'foo');
```

Now in R:

```
library(R.matlab)
foo <- readMat("foo.mat")
```

It turns out that `foo` is a list of 3 elements.

The first one is a raw vector:

```
foo$MCOS
# [1] 64 61 74 65 74 69 6d 65

rawToChar(foo$MCOS)
# [1] "datetime"
```

The second one is a matrix with 1 column and 6 rows:

```
foo[[2]]
           [,1]
[1,] -587202560
[2,]          2
[3,]          1
[4,]          1
[5,]          1
[6,]          1
```

The third one, which I guess is the date itself, is a matrix of integers with 1 row, 1056 columns, and lots of zeros.

```
head(foo[[3]],20)
[1]   0   1  73  77   0   0   0   0  14   0   0   0 128   3   0   0   6   0   0   0
```

I really don't understand this data representation, and how I could retrieve the date from this. I also tried saving a vector of datetimes instead of a single datetime. I get the same thing except the third entry has much more columns.

Comment: Could you provide us with the `foo.mat` file?